# Unable to make basic client certificate mapping to work on IIS

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, wcf-security, client-certificates

I am trying to make client certificate mapping (map an incoming client cert to a windows user) work on IIS 7+. I think I might be missing a step but I cant figure out. I have reproduced the problem with minimum steps as below:

**1. Create a hello world site**

[image]

**2. Configured the SSL**

[image]

3. **Configured the authentication**

[image]

**4. Configured the client cert using the plug in**

(NB: Tried this with both the plugin and by directly editing the config file)

[image]

5. Double checked client cert CA, Permissions etc
6. Tried to access the site

I get an HTTP 401.2 Error:
HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

[image]

7. The IIS trace 
   [image]

I think I am missing a step. Not sure. Really appreciate any help.

**Updates (thanks to comments):**

Added client certificate mapping authentication IIS feature:

[image]

Comment: What's the Windows edition you use here? You must enable certificate based authentication during IIS installation. From the authentication page I can see that you didn't install it yet. BTW, you are not using IIS 6.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi  for pointing out IIS version. I am doing this on windows 7 (Enterprise).

Comment: Thanks @LexLi  - Enabling certificate based authentication might be the step that I missed. Trying to figure out how to do that and hope we do not need active directory for that..

Comment: unless you are on Windows 7 Professional and above, I don't think you can test out certificate based authentication. It does not mandate AD, but require certain editions of Windows.

Comment: I have windows 7 (Enterprise) ...

Answer (score 0):

**I assume you only want pre-defined users with certificates to access the sites on the web server.** My screenshots are from IIS 7.5 but should be similar for your version 7. First set up the users in Active Directory or, if you have a stand-alone member server, in the local computer's local users. Make note of the password you use for them. Users will never need to know this password so you can make it horribly long and the same for all.

Next make a user group for these users and put them all in that user group. After the users are set up, you are ready to open IIS manager for the rest of the steps.

At the server level, enable Active Directory Client Certificate Authentication in the Authentication module.
[Server Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsnrS.png)

In the server level's Authorization Rules module, Deny Anonymous Users.
[Server Authorization Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqos4.png)

Now go to the site level. I think you have to do this at the site, not sub-site as in your image. Open the Authentication module and set all to disabled. 
[Site Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9LXs.png)

At the site level Authorization Rules, allow the role that is your Active Directory or local server user group name. 
[Site Authorization Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2zWw.png)

Now set up the users individually using one-to-one certificate mapping to the users you made earlier. You need to get each user's certificate, convert it to Base64, strip out the "Begin" and "End" certificate lines, and remove all the line feeds. Paste that certificate string into the account mapping with the user name and password.

Make sure you have installed a Certificate Revocation List handler in the web server.

Good luck!